# Javascript - how to replace an escape character followed by a 'G' in a string

Tags: javascript, string, replace, escaping

I have the following string 'Ganaway\Gannaway\Gansway' from a text file where I need to replace the escape character(s) with ' or '.

I've found answers here on Stackoverflow that suggest:

```
const name = 'Ganaway\Gannaway\Gansway';
name.replace(/\//g, ' or ');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkw6teu4/1/)

However when I debug it the name is already stripped automatically of the escape character before it reaches the .replace() code.

The result should be 'Ganaway or Gannaway or Gansway' but its unfortunately 'GanawayGannawayGansway'.

### Update:

The strings originate from a GEDCOM file which was exported from a genealogy website called Ancestry.com - here are some examples of the original text, it's not only the 'G' but various others that lead to

```
Regular expression is invalid: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u
```

errors:

1 NAME Emma Mae\May /Ganaway\Gannaway\Gansway/

or

1 NAME Niecy\Nicy Ann /Holy/

or

1 NAME Peggy Jo /Stewart\Uttrell/

Comment: There is no escape characters in that string - a `\G` in a string literal produces the content `G` as you've already seen. If you want to have a backslash, you need `\\G`. However, that only matters inside string literals and string templates. Where is that value coming from? If it's some sort of user input or otherwise just delivering string *content* to you, you likely don't have to care about escaping at all.

Comment: It's unfortunately user input. To give some more context, it's from a file format called GEDCOM, where the corresponding file was created from the popular genealogy website Ancestry.com by their export feature. I have hundreds of cases with various letters following the the single backslash like in Perkins\Gossett
Pendriar\Penry\Pender
Spencer\Patton\Myers or 1 NAME Niecy\Nicy Ann /Holy/

Comment: Then you'd just have backslashes, no escapes. [Try typing "a\b" here and click the button](https://jsbin.com/begipej/1/edit?html,js,console,output).The same case would be for reading text from files or wherever - the *content* of the strings is not escapes. It's just plain backslashes.

Comment: Thanks VLAZ, your solution `.replace(/\\/g, " or ")` does the job! Could you make your comment an answer so I can give you proper credit for it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use this syntax

```
const name = String.raw`Ganaway\Gannaway\Gansway`;
name.replace(/\\/g, ' or ');
```

Comment: Unfortunately the string is extracted from a file so your solution doesn't work as I need to use String.raw()

Comment: You could just do it like this<br> `String.raw(`${text  from file}`)`

Comment: It misses a parameter, getting: Unexpected
   token, expected ","

Comment: oh sorry, this is the correct text `String.raw(\`${text from file}\`)`

Comment: Abhijit, this leads to `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error. I appreciate your effort however it's not valid syntax and I don't know how to use this String.raw() function correctly. ```const name = 'Ganaway\Gannaway\Gansway';
    let name1 = String.raw(`${name}`);```

Comment: Could you share your source code through JSFiddle. I'll be able to help you as there isn't that much clarity in what you want and what I understand you want

Comment: @AbhijitBiswas it is not possible to turn string content already in the system to a raw output. `String.raw` works on literals *in the code*, not on string data that is already interpreted. And *there are no escapes in string content*. Escape sequences are ***only*** relevant when writing code and having a string literal - the escape sequence gets converted to string content of some sort (depending on the sequence). The content is just that - it the string contains a backslash, it's not "an escaped backslash" because that doesn't make any sense.